# Polyfilling Set in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, gatsby, polyfills

I'm using the default polyfill options though Gatsby is not correctly polyfilling on my site for iPhone 5 /5S and a few other older browsers (though works seems to work on IE11).

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set`

Not sure where i should set a work around polyfill or why Gatsby isn't polyfilling Set correctly on all devices.

I've tried the `gatsby-plugin-polyfill-io` plugin which seems to make things worse creating the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` instead.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the polyfill on gatsby-browser.js
For example:

```
export const onClientEntry = async () => {
  if (typeof IntersectionObserver === 'undefined') {
    await import('intersection-observer');
    console.log(' intersection-observer imported')
  }
}
```

Or gatsby-ssr.js

```
export const onRenderBody =({ setPostBodyComponents }, options) =>{
    setPostBodyComponents([
        <script
            src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js"
        />
    ])
}
```